# is this the right way to setup an upload path using a variable?

Tags: php, file, directory

I am trying to upload a document to a folder, whose name is inside the $folder variable.  the page goes blank and prints no error but when i connected using ssh and try to open that folder it says: Permission denied.

This is how i am doing it:

```
  $upload_path = '/stuff/$folder/';
```

And this is how i create the folders:

```
 mkdir("/stuff/$folder", 0700);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `$upload_path` should be set with `"` :

```
$upload_path = "/stuff/$folder/";
```

To access folder with ssh, you need to set different permissions on folder creation. the owner of the folder is the user that running apache on your server (mostly `www-data`, but the user connected thought ssh is not the same) :

```
mkdir("/stuff/$folder", 0755);
```

Comment: whats the diff between 777, 700, and 755

Comment: @KPO for more informations on permissions, I invite you to take a look at http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml#numeric

Answer (score 1):

it usual works with 775 (not to be writable by everyone)

```
mkdir("/stuff/$folder", 0775);
```

if that doesn't work try with writable by everyone, it must work

```
mkdir("/stuff/$folder", 0777);
```